# Getting correct order of execution of insert, update and delete operations before "SaveChanges"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We have a need to get the entities being added, modified or deleted in the same order as which it is being done on the database.

We are using the below code snippet by overriding the "SaveChanges" method in ObjectContext class to fetch the different entities who have been either added, modified or deleted.

*foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted))
            {

                 // Operations on each entity
            }*

Assume that we have two tables A & B in the database. These are unrelated. We do the below operations on these table using entity framework.

1. Insert a new row in A
2. Update a row in B
3. Insert a new row in B
4. Update a row in A (not the one inserted in step 1)
5. Delete a row in B (Not the rows affected in step 2 & 3)
6. Insert a new row in B
7. Insert a new row in A

While using the above code snippet, we noticed that the inserts, updates and deletes were grouped together, i.e., we got the entites in order 1,3,6,7,2,4,5.

It is mentioned in this post (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d8448144-05dd-4c34-b93c-9336c3b62f6e/) that there is no definite way to determine the order of inserts in operations done before a "SaveChanges".

Does the above code snippet fetch the correct order in which these operations are executed on the database.

In case this order is incorrect, is there any other way to get the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the order of operations. The only way to control the order is to run each operation separately (call `SaveChanges` after each operation).

Comment: More than changing the order of operations, I am more concerned about capturing the correct order of operations before a "SaveChanges" call. The question is whether the order which I am obtaining is the correct one or not.